# What would be the exact flow of actions if I click a submit button inside a view?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

What would be the exact flow or order of actions and rendering if I click my submit button which calls a javascript function and posts to a controller?

```
@section impScripts
     {

            <script type="text/javascript">

                function save() {

                    var u = {
                        UserName: document.getElementById('UserName').value,
                        Password: document.getElementById('Password').value
                    }

                    var users = JSON.stringify(u);

                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        url: '@Url.Action("Authenticate", "Users")',
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset= utf-8",
                        data: users,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (results) {



                        }
                    });
                };

            </script>
}
```

Button:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="save();" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
```

View:

```
@model HimHer.Models.Stories

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Authenticate";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<script type="text/javascript">


</script>


@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Stories</h4>
    <hr />

    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "form-control white" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control white" })
            </div>
        </div>


Controller:

[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Authenticate()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Authenticate(Stories u)
        {
            if (basicOps.getUsersLogin(u.UserName, u.Password)) 
            {
               u.UserID = 90099;
               //return RedirectToAction("GetImagesStories", "Stories", u);
               //return View("Authenticate");
               return Json(u);

            }

            //return View("Authenticate");
            return Json(u);


        }
```

Now I don't understand the exact flow after I click the submit button. I tried searching and doing it on my own but couldn't find the concrete knowledge about it. Help me with it.

Comment: **View** -> **Controller** -> **Action** (route values passed) -> **Model Updated** (optional)

Comment: Not related, but delete `var users = JSON.stringify(u);` and `contentType: "application/json; charset= utf-8",` and use `data: u,`. You should also be handling the forms submit event,  not the buttons click event.

Comment: but how the view would be rendered into html first since I have submitted it anywhere ?

Comment: And your not doing anything with the data your returning in the ajax `success` callback (in fact why are you returning the whole model back again instead of just that `UserID` value?) so its not clear what your wanting to do, or why your using ajax.

Comment: @StackyUnderflow In your code you pass to the `ActionResult` Method `Authenticate` which is held inside the `Users` controller. Adding the `[HttpPost]` attribute to the method tells the server that is the correct overloaded method to use when posting data from the view (client) to the server (controller). The controller updates the model, when you redirect back to the view the model has been repopulated with the updated data from the server. Razor pre-processes the data as HTML on the client side

Comment: @MasterYoda ok so when I click the SUbmit button it submits the view to the server and server sends back it's html rendered version and then ajax code does it work of posting data to the controller which then returns the view from server again in rendered form. Correct ?

Comment: Not in your code, when you POST to the server you are actually returning a JSON result. From what you are saying you need to update your model server with a json result and return the view with the model instead. Ill add an answer instead as its hard to explain in comments

Comment: @MasterYoda yeah, adding an answer would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Each component of MVC interacts with the other. Notice in the diagram below that:

- The view sends `HTTP` requests (*POST*, *GET* etc.) to the `controller`. `Controller` then updates the `model`.
- Now that the `model` has been updated, the `view` can use this `model` to render the form with the updated data.

[image: MVC Architecture]

---

### How does this compare to what you are doing?

- In your view, you pass the form values (mapped to your model) to the server (controller) via `AJAX`. Note that you can also do this using the [`@html.beginForm()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx) method instead of `AJAX`.
- When the request arrives server side it knows to check the `Users` controller as thats where you told it to look, it will also discover two instances of the `Authenticate` method (one of which is overloaded):

  ```
  //notice the [HttpGet] attribute, tells the server to get the view
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Authenticate(){return View();}

  //[HttpPost] tells it to use the overloaded method to accept a parameter (usually a routeValueDictionary object) 
  [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult Authenticate(Stories u){}
  ```
- Using a JsonResult return type for the method you are expecting to return a JsonResult instead of the view itself. From what you are saying you need to return an ActionResult instead returning the view with the updated Model instead, something like this (although I dont know what your model looks like):

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Authenticate(Stories u)
  {
      if (basicOps.getUsersLogin(u.UserName, u.Password)) 
      {
         u.UserID = 90099;
         //your view and controller are bound so no need to specify the view name, just pass the model back
         return View(u);
      }
      return View(u);
  }
  ```
- Now your model has been updated and your view has the latest model to render the HTML markup via `Razor`.

Comment: And why would OP want to return exactly the same view they already have( the view does not render anything relating to `UserID`)?.  And you have not shown how to update the DOM in the ajax call anyway

Comment: @StephenMuecke My assumption is that the AJAX call is simply to POST the data to the server as I mention the use of the beginForm() method supplied by MVC. If OP simply wants to return a JSON response from the server and render it as HTML in the AJAX callback function then that needs clarified. Anyways, the answer was posted as an explanation of how it works because i couldn't fit it into a comment, the overall question is about the flow of execution from view to controller to model to view